# Fresh installation, design issue with new products block

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, products, rwd-theme, product-images, ce-1.9.1.0

I've installed fresh magento 1.9.1.0 and I have a problem with new products block on homepage. New product images are too large. They should have been 260x260px but they are way larger than that.

I saw that file catalog/product/new.phtml is called but actually the file new.phtml does not exist on server, but on the previous version (1.9.0 i have installed on my local machine) does have that file. Here is a version in development to see what is going on - moodyandgloo.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right! CE 1.9.1.0 doesn't have a new.phtml in the rwd, while in CE 1.9.0.1 does.

Taking a look at your code, I can clearly see that you are using the new.phtml template from app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/new.phtml.

I can tell this because of some CSS classes on your website like:
[image]

That correlates to the base/default version of new.phtml:
[image]

The rwd/default version of new.phtml looks like:
[image]

The code for new.phtml for the rwd/default theme in CE 1.9.0.1 is this:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     rwd_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<h2 class="subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('New Products') ?></h2>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
        <?php /*if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid">
        <?php endif*/ ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <?php $_imgSize = 260; ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                </a>
                <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>
                <div class="actions">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ($_compareUrl = $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php /*if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==count($_products)): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif*/ ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes my friend! That was the missing file, you just have one <?php tag extra at the beginning (or one ?> missing at the end of the first comment section), because otherwise it displays blank homepage. And the commented css rule width 100%; from the previous answer can be undo-ed, because the images won't display correctly.

Comment: And one more thing...I wonder, how that file went missing from the fresh installation? It was a download.php installation and it could be something went wrong during install? How can I be sure that I have all the other mandatory (or not) files? Is it a manual upload of files directly to my server better way to start installation than the download one?

Comment: It was missing in a clean copy of CE 1.9.1.0 that I downloaded about 90 minutes ago. I am going to submit a bug ticket to Magento to inform them of the missing file. To answer "how can I be sure that I have all the other files", I would strongly suggest to get your site on version control. This will allow you to diff code a lot easier. When you first start out, it seems like a pain, however it it a necessary tool to fix issues like this.

Comment: Thank you again. And I was wrong about that <?php tag, i simply copied it wrong :S

Answer (score 1):

The css style is overwriting the defined with. Check style.css line 4278.

```
.products-grid .product-image img {
   /* width: 100%; */
   height: auto;
}

.products-grid .product-image img {
  /* width: 100%; */
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but that block still has some problems. border is wider than the image. I just want 6 images in the same row, like it was on a previous version. I can't figure it out where the problem is because it is a fresh install.

Comment: Try to view the changelog. Maybe they have changed the design ?